# Ampersand with certain spacing not allowed in Category name

Tags: categories

When I use an ampersand (&) in a Category name with spaces **in a certain order** I get an error that does not allow me to submit the change. Using EE v.2.9.2.

**Error:** "The data you submitted did not pass our security check."
This seems to be the "invalid_xss_check" error.

I have tried to change the Category group to "Allow all HTML" and to also encode all HTML but I get the same results.

Here is what works and what doesn't work (screenshot below).

**Works:**

> 1. "One[space]&[space]Two"
> 2. "One&[space]Two"

**Does Not Work:**

> 3. "One&Two"   ( <--- This is the one I want )
> 4. "One[space]&Two"
> 5. "One[space]&amp[space]Two" - (going insane...)

**Screenshot:**
[image: Category Errors]

Comment: @foamcow is right, thanks.  I want:  
> One&amp;Two

Comment: FWIW I got this same error when attempting to submit _Category Description_ html with inline style elements, e.g. this is rejected `<a class="nobarlink" style="display:inline; padding: 0.5ex; margin:0;" ...` while this is ok: `<a class="nobarlink" ...`. Ideally it's better to solve this upstream in the template CSS, but frustrating to have to add yet another special case for one category in a site-wide resource. I just used mysql workbench to edit table directly. Oh well, at least I know _why_ because of this thread. Thanks for that.

Comment: I can't edit the table because this is for the users to play with. I still haven't found the rules for what can and can't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
One &amp; Two
```

Note the semi-colon after the HTML entity - you missed that on your version.

Comment: Doh... I love you.